# How to keep the floatingActionButton fixed at is original position when scrolling the recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I need help to keep the fab shown in pics at a fixed position when scrolling up or down i cant find anything on google as most search results return information on hiding the fab when scrolling
Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/accent"> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/accent"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"

/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addmorefab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_marginBottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_marginRight"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/listView"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    /></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I even tried to make two constraint layouts it didnt work

I also tried using recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
It worked but it was limiting the scrolling of the recyclerview.
On the second picture i want the fab to remain fixed where it is not scrolling

[image: I want the fab fixed where it is currently even if i scroll up or down not like how it is happening on the second picture][1]]

[image: This fab scrolls scrolls upwards together with appbarlayout this view is inflated]

Comment: Why not keep the FAB **inside** the constraint layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this view if you want your bright button to remain fixed while scrolling through the recycler.

I used Android X libraries and you can use lower version libraries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addmorefab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer i tried but it doesnt work

Comment: Give a more complete explanation or send your project so that we know exactly what you want

Comment: Okay what happens is that when am scrolling the recyclerView the fab and toolbar scrolls up until the toolbar which is inside appbar layout is gone. What i want is to stop the scrolling of the fab as am scrolling the recyclerView